# Why do I get the "Your computer appears to be infected with a malware" message?

Tags: facebook

When trying to log in to Facebook, the message comes up:

> Your computer appears to be infected with a malware

[image: Your computer appears to be infected with a malware]
I've tried different browsers, same result with all. Apparently the session thinks my computer is infected. I really did not know that it was infected. It's a Mac. If that's the case it's only this user. Might be something else the browser is complaining about. I'm on OS X 10.6 with Firefox 8.

How can the browser know that my computer is infected?

**Update:** 
It turned out that Facebook has shut my account down without notice, NOT telling me, right. The least they could do is send me an email telling me but I guess they don't bother. The error message is pointless.

Comment: You seem to be confused. Sathya perfectly answered your question. This does not have **anything** to do with browsers at all. I removed the parts from your question that were misleading, if that's okay for you. Again: This has nothing to do with the browser or how the browser works.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @slhck I'm just wondering about the *Facebook* and *tried different browsers* parts.

Comment: @Jarleif Just because the browser doesn't know, it doesn't mean Google won't know. In essence: You can't be sure that your computer is *not* infected. It weird though because it's a Mac.

Comment: @Daniel, Here you go :)

Comment: Infected with _a malware_? That's terrible English. I would be immediately suspicious of whether or not that web page is legitimate. Had I seen that I'd poke around in the source. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox uses [Phishing and Malware Protection](http://Phishing%20and%20Malware%20PROTECTION), which is a [Google service](http://www.google.com/tools/firefox/safebrowsing/index.html). Basically, it checks the sites that you visit against lists of reported phishing and malware sites. [This link](http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/wiki/Protocolv2Spec) explains the technical details of the Safe Browsing protocol.

Google has an [support article](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1182191) on this notice as well.

> #### Why does Google think my computer is infected?
>
> Some forms of malicious software will alter your computer settings to redirect some or all of your traffic through a proxy controlled by the attacker. When you use Google, the proxy forwards your query to the real Google servers to fetch the search results. If our system detects that a search came through one of these proxies, we display the warning.

Comment: Beat me to it. Just to be clear: There's no way on earth a browser itself would scan your computer for malware. Even more so: There's no interface that would allow websites to ask this information about your computer. (That is, without any additional plugins)

Comment: Good as a start but could you perhaps be more specific? Helps a lot though.

Comment: @Jarleif what specifics are you looking for? The linked articles pretty much explain your situation

Comment: @Jarleif For Facebook, I would look at the following help page: [I am blocked or disabled](https://www.facebook.com/help/blockedordisabled) – if you have specific questions about Facebook, I would rather ask them at [Webapps.SE], because they would be off-topic here.

Comment: Jarlief, I would second @slhck's suggestion. This appears to be specific to facebook and I'm not sure if that's a legit message..

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. I'll do that then. *(((for now NOT beeing logged in to fb is a productivity enhancement... Meaning. Not needing facebook now)))